# Prevent Mac terminal from changing tabs when reopened

Tags: macos, terminal

Whenever I open the terminal app after it was minimized, it often changes tab and go back to a particular tab (which tab in particular is not very important). Can someone suggest a workaround for this problem?

Currently on Mojave OSX (10.14.4) and had this problem with High Sierra too previously.

Comment: Well, actually it is important. What is special about the tab it goes back to? Is there a binary running there (besides bash), does it contain output created while the window was minimized?

Comment: @nohillside When I said that, I meant it is kind of arbitrary in that the it returns to the first tab sometimes, or to second tab sometimes etc. Just noticed that it is always returning to the oldest tab among the existing tabs. Also, the cursor stays put in the same tab where it was when the tab was minimized, but visually the tab shifts to the oldest tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead of minimising by pressing minimise button, using <kbd>⌘  H</kbd> (COMMAND H) instead? Then it will not shift to the oldest tab.

Then, use <kbd>⌘ ⇥</kbd> (COMMAND TAB) to navigate the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a decent workaround. Yeah, hiding and then opening the terminal again is not changing the tabs.